# Search directory and store in hash

Tags: perl, hash, subdirectory

From user's input, I should able to search its sub directories until the fixed directory which named 'list'. The question is how to store the path into hash so that I could retrieve the data and display it afterwards.

my directory tree:

```
                        ->blue    -->Aug21   --->projA  ---->list   ----->name
/tmp/general/place/brand->red     -->Jan03
                        ->yellow  -->June22  --->projB  ---->list
```

directory.pl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Searching Directory...\n";
&search_dir('/tmp/general/place/brand'); #could be 'tmp/general/place/brand/blue/Aug21'
my ($input,$tt,$str,$fn,@pp,@cap);

sub search_dir{
$input=shift;
opendir DH,$input or die"$!";
while($_=readdir(DH)){
    next if $_ eq "." or $_ eq "..";
    if ($_ eq "list"){
        $fn = $input.'/'.$_;
        push @pp, $fn;
        return;
        }
    else{
        $fn = $input.'/'.$_;
        }

    if(-d $fn){
        push @cap,$fn;
        }
}

if(scalar @cap == 0){
    return;
    }
foreach (@cap){
    &search_dir($_) ;
    }
}

if (@pp){
    print "Located directory...\n";
    foreach $tt (@pp){
            $str='/tmp/general/place/brand';
            $tt=~ s/$str//g;
            print $tt,"\n";
    #Hash?  $file{$color}{$date}{$quantity}{$list}= split (/\//,$tt);
    }
}
else {
     print "Could not locate directory\n";
    }
```

Expected Output:

```
Searching Directory...
Located Directory...
/blue/Aug21/projA/list
/yellow/June22/projB/list
Info  :1
Color :blue
Date  :Aug21
Project :projA
Info  :2
Color :yellow
Date  :June22
Project:projB
```

Comment: Use [`File::Find`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3A%3AFind)

Comment: My question is how to store the path which I have searched into hash. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, using File::Find you can replace most of your code. Not sure I understand your question. Do you not know how hashes work? `$hash{path} = $path`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under linux it maybe easier to use find. Quick and dirty but it will do the job.

```
my @dirs = `/usr/bin/find -name "/tmp/general/place/brand/" -type d`;
chomp(@dirs);
my $data = {};
foreach my $dir (@dirs){
  my @path = split(/\//,$dir);
  #you have found a list in the right depth
  if (scalar(@path) >= 7 && $path[7] eq 'list'){
    $dir =~ s!/tmp/general/place/brand!!is;
    print "Found $dir\n";
    print "Color :".$path[4];
    ...
  }
}
```